# I can't change char pointers (arrays)

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I have some function like this:

```
void MClass::GetS(char* buf, int max) const  {
char *temp = new char[max];
temp[max] = '\0';
for (int i = 0; i < max - 1; i++)
    temp[i] = src[i]; // src is class member (char *)
buf = temp; // buf is null after this o.O
}
```

So, I can't change buf value in this function. Why does it take place?

Comment: Your code is leaking memory btw

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong here. Why are you using the `new` operator? Why not a `vector<char>` or `string`? If you were writing [tag:c], you should declare as `void MClass::GetS(char** buf, int max) const` and change the last line to `*buf = temp`, but you're not writing C so don't do that.

Comment: The `buf` pointer is being passed by value so won't be visible to the caller. However, why not use a `std::string` ?

Comment: Why? Same code works in another place (if I do that: src = temp).

Comment: @m0stwanted No it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, I can't use any STL classes and double pointers

Comment: @m0stwanted: either you pass `buf` by reference, or you use `std::copy()` to copy the content of the buffer pointed to by `temp` into the buffer pointed to by `buf`. Your last instruction has no effect here

Comment: The `char*&` to pass pointer by reference.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain, really. If `char**` is not permitted and STL is not permitted then it is the only option, unless the function returns the array.

Comment: @m0stwanted Is this a homework problem?

Comment: temp[max] = 0; is a write off the end of the array bug.  After that, everything else is suspect...

Comment: No, it is not a home work.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I know that I do, it is normal ;) It is't a bug

Comment: If it's not homework, why on earth are you sticking to that function signature? And why aren't you using STL?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: What's the point in pursuing the issue of whether it's homework or not? The homework tag is banned.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I'm just trying to understand the limitations of the problem.

Comment: Just nevermind about STL. I want to know, why if I change buf variable in function, it is NOT changed even in function?

Comment: I have downvoted, as you're not listening to people trying and very willing to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems:

1. You are writing off the end of your heap array with `temp[max] = '\0';` - this places a 0 1 spot after your buffer.
2. Who knows how big src is.  You are passing in a "max" and reading against a src without check 
   size - very dangerous.
3. You are returning a pointer with a pointer.  You need to pass in a double pointer and to get the actual pointer value returned correctly (or return the pointer in the return statement.)

When in doubt, trace your code in a debugger.  My guess is that your compiler is helping you by opimizing the last assignment away and leaving it as NULL for you - then letting you merrily crash later on with your now corrupted heap and memory leak...

Answer (score 3):

Passing `char *` to a function passes a copy of a pointer to that function. You can think of it as the pointer being passed by value. Modifying this copied pointer doesn't change the original pointer.

You need to pass it by reference (reference to pointer):

```
void MClass::GetS(char *&buf, int max) const
```

or pointer (pointer to pointer):

```
void MClass::GetS(char **buf, int max) const
```

or return the pointer:

```
char *MClass::GetS(int max) const
```

Comment: Yes, I understand all of this. But why I can't change buf variable in the function? If I do, for example, this code: buf = new char, or another - my pointer is null.

Comment: @m0stwanted: Apparently you don't understand all of this, because the answer to that question is quite explicitly stated in the opening paragraph.

Comment: I know that I can use double pointers or reference to return my value, but why I can't change it inside my function?

Comment: @m0stwanted Read the damn opening paragraph.  What is unclear about that?

Comment: You can change it, but parameters are local inside the function. Pointers are values. The **pointee** (the memory behind the pointer) can be changed (so that it affects the code outside), but not the **pointer** (it will remain unchanged outside and changes remain local inside the function). By doing this *twice*, you change the pointer so it is affected from outside. To simplify syntax, I'd recommend reference to pointer.

Comment: @leemes But if I look in debug and do that code, I also have no changes in local:
// funct start, buf = NULL
char z = 'W';
buf = &z; // after this, LOCAL in function buf = NULL.

Comment: Then your debugger is broken. Try `std::cout << (void*)buf << "\n";`

Comment: I try another debugger (GDB), so it says that buf is "synthetic pointer"

Comment: @m0stwanted Maybe its creation is optimised away because it's never used (speculative) (even though it is assigned a value, but this doesn't really matter), try Rob's suggestion (add that to the end of the function).

Answer (score 0):

You are refering to an element beyond the array (since it has MAX elements and index starts and 0) hence UB/Error.
Char array always needs 1 extra char for the null character btw.

More info on what src is would be helpful too.

But in this case it seams that you are changing the value of buf (as a parameter) while not returning/changing the value you passed in.

You need to pass a pointer to pointer or reference to pointer (* *) or (* &) not just a simple pointer.

Comment: I know it, but my function must copy a string into a given plain null-terminated C-style string buffer. So, if caller send null, behavior is undefined

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly a homework problem.

I'm guessing you are being passed a buffer `buf` of size `max`. You don't need `temp` and you should be very careful not to write off the end. Something like...

```
void MClass::GetS(char* buf, int max) const  {
  if(!buf) {
    return;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < max - 1; i++) {
      buf[i] = src[i]; // How long is `src`?
  }
}
```

This is not modern C++, and if you were doing  this for yourself, the function would be declared as `std::string MClass::GetS() const { return src; }` (assuming `src` is `null` terminated). Please correct your tutor.